# How do I hide the menu bar?

Tags: macos, batman-arkham-city

How do I hide the Menu Bar in *Batman: Arkham City GOTY*? It shows up when I am full screen. I've searched the preference file and didn't find a relevant key nor can I find an option in the startup menu for the Menu Bar.

Comment: Please give a comment when downvoting

Comment: @BlueTrin commenting with voting is entirely optional.

Comment: @TZHX, alot of things are optional, in life and here, but it still gives better feedback to explain why you downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is either a one-off issue or disabling the dock has fixed it (on a subsequent relaunch with the dock enabled the menu bar was still gone).